# empty extentX report

Tags: mongodb, extentreports, extent

extentX looks like the perfect solution, a collection of test results.

However, I have followed all the instructions and got everything up and running but it seems the test information does not seem to be getting to the extent page.

It's empty. I can see from the dashboard tests have run but the project is Default and clicking into them shows no information, but I can see it's getting some data as it shows how many tests have been run and how much info has been passed.

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong?

I can see the standard extent report works perfectly, but it does seem to be passed up to the extentX server.

I am running everything locally for the moment as its a proof of concept.

I am using version 3.0.1 of extentreports

any help getting this working will be appreciated, also if anyone knows any alternatives for displaying multiple test reports on a single hub that would be great

---

Using the following page - https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/652#issuecomment-254078018

I managed to get a little bit further but now I am getting the following error

**java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**
at the following line

**ExtentTest parent = ExtentTestManager.createTest(testName);**

Here is my TestNG Base

public class TestBase {

```
private String uri;
protected Logger APPLICATION_LOGS = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
private static ExtentReports extent;
private ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> parentTest;
private ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> test;
public static ExtentTest childTest;

protected String getUri() {
    return uri;
}

@BeforeSuite
@Parameters({"env"})
public void initialiseReport(String env) {

    ExtentXReporter extentxReporter = new ExtentXReporter("localhost:27017");
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(("user.dir") + "/target/ExtentReports.html");


    extentxReporter.config().setServerUrl("localhost:1337");
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter, extentxReporter);
}

@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"protocol", "env", "server", "port", "endPoint", "testName"})
public void initialiseURI(String protocol, String env, String server, String port, String endPoint, String testName) {
    uri = protocol + env + "." + server + ".mcom:" + port + "/" + endPoint;
    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Will use the following URI: " + uri);

    baseURI = uri;
    given().when().post().then().statusCode(200);

    ExtentTest parent = ExtentTestManager.createTest(testName);
    parentTest.set(parent);

}

@BeforeMethod
public final void beforeMethod(Method method) {

    childTest = parentTest.get().createNode(method.getName());
    test.set(childTest);

}

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
    switch (result.getStatus()) {
        case ITestResult.FAILURE:
            childTest.fail(result.getThrowable());
            break;
        case ITestResult.SKIP:
            childTest.skip(result.getThrowable());
            break;
        case ITestResult.SUCCESS:
            childTest.pass("Passed");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@AfterSuite
public void completeReport() {

    ExtentManager.getExtent().flush();
}
```

}

---

Managed to get it working using this git project

https://github.com/saikrishna321/extent_reports

But my extentX page is still empty, its showing how many tests have run but no report is being attached.

Comment: Unclear from the question, what you've tried where it fails with what error/exceptions OR what you expect as output for a given input etc. I don't see this relevant to maven/java anyway as of now as well.

Comment: The tests are written in java, and are executed in maven which is why i have tagged them in. Maybe this is not best practice but i thought it gave a little more information into why its not working.

Comment: But you forgot to share what's written in java(related to the question) and maven(in terms of build)

Comment: It is not really that relevant to the question if you know what extentX is, i tagged java and maven because the project is built with them but the issue lies with extentX....

Comment: I am still struggling to get my extentx server to look remotely like the sample shown here - http://extentx.herokuapp.com/#/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i was using the wrong extentX distrubution.

When downloading the zip from the wbesite - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByJmgAhaLx0GcmVYNkhBSThUcG8

It worked